# Does using the Knock spell on the front door of Icespire Hold wake Cryovain?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hearing, dragon-of-icespire-peak

I examined the Icespire Hold dungeon in the D&D 5e *Essentials Kit*. The Icespire Hold door(between H1 and H2) is not locked, but I think the PCs I DM for might think it *is* locked.
One of them is a sorcerer, and could possibly cast the *knock* spell on the door. Cryovain, the white dragon boss of the dungeon, is likely to be asleep at the time when they arrive. There are several noises that wake him up: ringing a bell, whispering in his ear, some spells (they only list *thunderclap* as one of the spells that would wake him up), etc. **Would** ***knock*** **count as a spell that would wake Cryovain?**

Comment: [Is this title a spoiler and how would we avoid the spoiler if so?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/is-this-title-a-spoiler-and-how-would-we-avoid-the-spoiler-if-so)

Comment: @FerventHippo Is it really *that big* of a spoiler, even?

Comment: I have no idea as I haven't played the adventure. But from the title I can deduce that 1. a creature named Cryovain resides in a place named Icespire Hold, and 2. they are sleeping. Maybe your PCs are reading up on data structures for C# and see this in the "hot network questions", thus being spoiled about the contents of your adventure. Hence the related meta question.

Comment: @FerventHippo Cryovain is a white dragon. At the point where the PCs go *to* Icespire Hold, they would already know where this is and that Cryovain lives *at* Icespire Hold.

Comment: Maybe the adventurers are oblivious that large noises may cause them troubles. I'm nitpicking but I think the question is valid: is this detailed information needed in the title for the question to make sense? Would "what is the effect of using the Knock spell on the front door of Icespire Hold" work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### *Knock* and *thunderwave* have similar volume.

The adventure states:

> Someone or something makes a noise loud enough to interrupt the dragon’s slumber. Noises that qualify include the clap of a *thunderwave* spell

*Thunderwave* states:

> the spell emits a thunderous boom audible out to 300 feet.

*Knock* similarly states:

> When you cast the spell, a loud knock, audible from as far away as 300 feet, emanates from the target object.

So *knock* and *thunderwave* have similar volumes, as they’re audible from the same distance. Ergo, if *thunderwave* awakens the dragon, so does *knock*.

It should be noted that while you mentioned *thunderclap* in the question, the adventure mentions *thunderwave*, and *thunderclap* is not as loud as *knock* or *thunderwave*:

> You create a burst of thunderous sound that can be heard up to 100 feet away.

The DM determines from where it is loud enough to awaken the dragon.

Comment: May be helpful to include that the diameter of Icespire Hold doesn't exceed about 200' and is surrounded by ice. On the other hand, Cryovain is also described as dim-witted.

Comment: @NautArch On the other other hand, dimwitted != hard of hearing..

Comment: @Questor oh geez, no. It’s Hearing!= understanding

Comment: Ice is a formidable transmitter of sound - smacking something into an ice wall can be *heard* quite some meters resounding from the wall where the air has not yet brought the sound!